# When should I use a upgradable lock?

Tags: multithreading, boost, synchronization

I have used sharable lock and exclusive lock, but I don't have the opportunity to use upgradable lock. If there is a need to `upgrade` from sharable lock to exclusive lock, just unlock the  sharable lock and get the exclusive lock. So under what situation should I use the upgradable lock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would upgrade if you need to upgrade and unlocking is not an option.

Consider an atomic transaction that read some information under the read-lock. When the time has come to commit the updated information, you cannot afford to relinquish the read-lock right before acquiring the write-lock, because this means another party might have mutated the shared state in such a way that your transaction doesn't apply anymore.

This is where you upgrade the lock - which guarantees that no other party will acquire the write lock in the mean time.

IOW: unlocking yields control. The other way to solve this would be to acquire the write lock always if you /might/ want to write something later. But this leads to excess exclusive locking, and is precisely what reader/writer locks were intended to prevent.